# How to goes again to zero when the value of the variable reaches the full scale? sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in SQL Server for a counter of the total production parts so I will be update this value in one each new finished product.

I know each variable on SQL have a max scale to store in my case this variable is `BIGINT` so I need to reset this variable to zero when reaches the full scale.

Thanks for all!.

Comment: Can you afford to use the `modulo operator (%)`?

Comment: I don't know how many products you intend to sell, but `BIGINT` is 64 bits wide, so you should be fine for pretty much ever.

Comment: If you use a `BIGINT` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 9.22 quintillion limit ....  do you **really** think this will be a problem in your case??

Comment: When you exceed 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 products you may need to worry about this. But as long as you have less you should be ok.

Comment: Once you have a product for every valid `bigint` value and reset to `0` (or `1`), how will you tell the difference between the 'original' `1` and the 'new' `1`?